# EE4 Module Tab on Template Editor Page

Tags: templates, add-on, add-on-development, module, addons

Is there a way to add a tab on the publish form within the Template Manager like it is with the Channels?

For example, the Template Manager has the default Edit, Notes, Settings and Access form tabs. I wanted to add another from my custom module.

Is this currently possible within the core API?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own module to add a TAB in channel entries. You need to follow the documentation of creating a module.

This [URL](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/modules.html) will help you to create a module. Your structure should be like given image below:

[image]

On your UPD file install function, remember to put `has_publish_fields` value as `y`. otherwise your data you want to display in tab will show on `publish` Tab.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I understand how to add one to the channel entries, but my question was if there is a way to add one to the Template Editor inside the Template Manager?

Comment: I am afraid not.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks again for the confirmation!